# Unreal Engine 4 reference a pawn actor and possess it

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I've been working with Unreal Engine 4's blueprint system, and got stuck when trying to possess a pawn. There are two pawns, Player1 and Player2, and each inherit from their own blueprint class. The Player1 actor is automatically possessed at the start of the level. When the player clicks on a space on the screen, it will fire a projectile. If the projectile hits the opposing player, it's game over, but if it hits terrain, the second player should have a chance to go. I've made the game over work, but I'm having an issue with the possession of the second player when the projectile hits terrain. (Terrain, in this instance, is just an actor called WorldCollision, not actual terrain.) [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYdjg.jpg) is an example of my blueprint

I've already attempted casting to Player2, but I can't figure out what in inherits from. I've tried the PlayerControler, PlayerControledPawn, and GetParent and GetParentActor, but I either got a warning, or it didn't work at all. The next thing I tried was creating references to them in the GameMode as Pawn variables, but when compiled, the engine wouldn't allow me to modify the variable's Default Value, image here: [Variable Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrVHA.jpg).
However, I could modify the Default Value of an Object variable, but it wasn't compatible with the plug-in for the Possess node.

The blueprint itself is the projectile actor's blueprint

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you simply need to wire up an execute pin and a reference to the pawn you want to possess into your possess node.

Based on what you've said, you should be pulling an execution wire from where you detect a terrain hit and wiring it into possess. Possess will also need a reference to the pawn that you want to control, which should be wired to the "In Pawn" pin on the possess node. You shouldn't need to do any casting since you are using APawn for your player characters.